# Why is tkinter animation so slow the longer canvas.create_text is?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

So I wanted to make an animation where a very long string with bunch of linebreaks will appear to be falling in the screen. I noticed that the longer the string is, especially with line breaks, the slower the animation becomes.

Here's a simple code that runs fast because I only have 1 line of string plus the linebreak:

```
from tkinter import *
def shift():
    canvas.move(text,0,1)
    canvas.after(1,shift)
root=Tk()
canvas=Canvas(root,bg='black')
canvas['width']=1920
canvas['height']=1080
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
text_var="grtgliwjltjlk34jklsdgwelfjqwekfjlqkwejflkqwejflkqjwefkljqwelkfjl.\n"
text=canvas.create_text(0,0,text=text_var,font=('Times New Roman',-58,'bold'),fill='white')
canvas.moveto(text,0,0)

shift()
root.mainloop()
```

Now when I multiply the string by 100:

```
text_var="grtgliwjltjlk34jklsdgwelfjqwekfjlqkwejflkqwejflkqjwefkljqwelkfjl.\n"*100
```

Its just super slow! Does this have to do with tkinter? is it a limitation? Should I be using a different library? or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Right now you are trying to move the text 1000 times a second (1000 FPS). Most people wouldn't notice if you tried moving the text 60 times a second (60 FPS). Also you are trying to move the text at 1000 pixels a second. Isn't that a bit too much? Don't forget that the `.after` time is in milliseconds.

Comment: @TheLizzard You're right, I didn't realize 1000fps was unnecessary. It looks fine now I made it 60fps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be traceable to using a proportional rather than [monospaced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) font. As a quick experiment you can use `font=('Consolas',-58,'bold')` and you will see it scroll much faster, even with 100 lines. (You might want to tweak the font size in this case.)

With non-monospaced font, Tkinter needs to compute the spacing for each line. Using something like `Consolas` removes that computation.

Comment: This is true, I have also noticed after changing the fonts that different fonts had different effects on the slowness. But didn't quite know what causes these differences. Thanks for this.